# How to get node attributes of specific type in xml?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xslt

I am using the following code:

```
System.Xml.XmlDocument document = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
document.Load(@"D:\Files\OCR\" + FileUpload1.FileName + ".xml");

if (document.HasChildNodes)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder positions = new StringBuilder();
    XmlElement root = document.DocumentElement;
    XmlNodeList nodes = document.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//char[@confidence]");
}
```

The problem is that document.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//char[@confidence]") returns null.

When I write the following code the result is shown.

```
int nodesCount = Document.DocumentElement.ChildNodes[0].ChildNodes.Count;
```

How do I count all nodes with attributes confidence?

Comment: `SelectNodes` always returns an `XmlNodeList` and never null.

Comment: But in my code it is returning null.count =0

Comment: The Count can of course be zero if the XmlNodeList is empty but the result is an `XmlNodeList` and not null. Show us your XML document and we can help with the XPath expression. Or try `//*[@confidence]`, that way the resulting `XmlNodeList` should contain all elements that have a `confidence` attribute.

Comment: thanks Martin Honnen i got the result with //*[@confidence].

Answer (score 1):

You could use XDocument and some effective LINQ:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"D:\Temp\file.xml");
int count = doc.Root.Descendants().Count(e => e.Attribute("confidence") != null);
Console.Write("Count:" + count);
Console.Read();
```

Output: 4

And my file.xml contains the following:

```
<something>
    <char confidence="1">
    </char>
    <char confidence="2">
    </char>
    <char confidence="3">
    </char>
    <notchar confidence="1">
    </notchar>
</something>
```

The above code checks all descendants for the attribute "confidence". If you want only elements that have the name "char", you can use the following:

```
int count = doc.Root.Descendants().Count(e => e.Name == "char" && e.Attribute("confidence") != null);
```

Output: 3